# Coroutine awaiter methods are called for seemingly not-existing object

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

In the following program there are two coroutines. `coroutine_A` is empty and simply calls `co_return`, and `coroutine_B` just switches to the first coroutine once by calling `co_await`.

Also the program prints every time a `task` object is created or destructed and each time the methods `await_ready` and `await_suspend` are called:

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>

struct task {
    struct promise_type;
    
    using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

    task(handle_type h) : handle(h) {
        std::cout << "task ctor " << this << '\n';
    }
    ~task() {
        std::cout << "task dtor " << this << '\n';
    }

    struct promise_type {
        auto get_return_object() {
            return task{handle_type::from_promise(*this)};
        }

        auto initial_suspend() {
            return std::suspend_always {};
        }

        auto unhandled_exception() {}

        auto final_suspend() noexcept {
            return std::suspend_always{};
        }

        void return_void() {}
    };

   handle_type handle;

   void await_resume() {
       std::cout << "await_resume " << this << '\n';
       handle.resume();
   }

   auto await_suspend(handle_type) {
       std::cout << "await_suspend " << this << '\n';
       return handle;
   }

   auto await_ready() {
       std::cout << "await_ready " << this << '\n';
       return false;
   }
};

int main() {
  task coroutine_A = []() ->task {
    co_return;
  }();

  task coroutine_B = [&coroutine_A]() ->task {
    co_await coroutine_A;
  }();

  coroutine_B.handle.resume();
}
```

What surprises me is that the program built by GCC prints here, for example:

```
task ctor 0x7ffdef0f9458
task ctor 0x7ffdef0f9450
await_ready 0x431f30
await_suspend 0x431f30
task dtor 0x7ffdef0f9450
task dtor 0x7ffdef0f9458
```

Please note that `this` inside `task::await_ready` and `task::await_suspend`is not equal to any constructed instance of `task`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WPnGqdhjr

Is it a GCC bug or there is some other explanation?

Comment: If you suspect it to be a gcc bug, please give the gcc version you are using. How are clang and msvc handling it?

Comment: @JHBonarius, it happens in GCC 11 and in trunk; Clang and MSVC does not have similar issue as far as I see.

Comment: Your `await_resume` calls `handle.resume()` but the coroutine is already resumed. This is a double-resume, which is UB.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thanks, fortunately `await_resume` is not called at all in this program, so we can leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

First, your example exhibit undefined behaviour. Let's look at this:

```
task coroutine_B = [&coroutine_A]() ->task {
    co_await coroutine_A;
}();

coroutine_B.handle.resume();
```

Your `task::promise_type` suspends in initial suspend so line `co_await coroutine_A;` is invoked only after `coroutine_B.handle.resume();`. But your lambda is already destroyed by that time. So it's capture (reference to coroutine_A) is destroyed as well.

If we add [task copy constructor](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K58xEqb4n) to your original code we will see that it is called and `await_ready` and `await_suspend` are called from that copy:

```
task ctor 0x7ffff491d1f8
task ctor 0x7ffff491d1f0
task copy to 0x1734f30
await_ready 0x1734f30
await_suspend 0x1734f30
task dtor 0x7ffff491d1f0
task dtor 0x7ffff491d1f8
```

Initially I was surprised that there were no corresponding destructor call of that newly created task. But your task class never call `handle.destroy()` and `task::promise_type` suspends in final suspend. So all objects alive by the end of the coroutine are never destroyed.

After [fixing that undefined behaviour](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oE83aMTjc) there is no copy at all:

```
task ctor 0x7ffeee8b8860
task ctor 0x7ffeee8b8858
await_ready 0x7ffeee8b8860
await_suspend 0x7ffeee8b8860
task dtor 0x7ffeee8b8858
task dtor 0x7ffeee8b8860
```

Unfortunately I don't know whether a copy of task is allowed in the `co_await coroutine_A;` as [evaluation of an await-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await#3) is not clear enough for me to find it out.

> Please note that this inside task::await_ready and task::await_suspendis not equal to any constructed instance of task.
> Is it a GCC bug or there is some other explanation?

That task is created by copy constructor. As in your example task does not have user provided copy constructor with logging that was not obvious from program output. Unfortunately your example exhibit undefined behaviour.

After fixing undefined behaviour gcc version of the example makes no copies too. Maybe that coping was related to having UB in the program.

Comment: When I fix the UAF bug, the copy disappears: `task coroutine_B = [](auto&coroutine_A) ->task { co_await coroutine_A; }(coroutine_A);`. It is the `std::move(coroutine_A)` that is triggering the copy in gcc.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, missed that `std::move` while cleaning up example. I added it while fixing not calling "handle.destroy" to see if it was the reason and forgot to revert it.

Comment: Thanks. In your fixed version, lambda capture is replaced with function argument, I think this changes the behavior of GCC. If we keep lambda capture and make sure that lambda object is not destructed prematurely, the issue persists: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/chY1s8xW1

Comment: @Fedor What issue specifically? Is your question about whether a copy in the `co_await coroutine_A;` is allowed by the standard or about unknown instance of task from which await_ready and await_suspend is called?

Comment: Actually both questions are of interest to me: 1) whether a copy is allowed, 2) and why the copy is not destructed even after I removed the UB.

Comment: *1) whether a copy is allowed* You probably should ask another question with tag "language-lawyer" for this. *2) and why the copy is not destructed even after I removed the UB* As I written in the answer this is because your `task` never calls `handle.destroy()` and all objects (even that task copy) are never destroyed as coroutine frame is never destroyed by your program. Your program has memory leak.